# How to redirect to another page from within Xamarin Webviews Navigating event

Tags: xamarin, navigation, redirect

I want to do a very simple thing: if a person goes to a specific page within my webview I want them to be redirected to a different page. I want to do this to prevent an errorpage from showing on session timeout. So this needs to happen from within Xamarin because I have to resend the user credentials.

To do that, I believe I have to catch the Navigating event, check if the webpage corresponds with the page I don't want to see. Cancel the Navigating event and set the browser URL to the page I want to redirect to.

```
private void Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    String url = e.Url;
    if (url.Contains("unauthenticated.xhtml"))
    {
        url = getURL();
        e.Cancel = true;
        browser.Source = url;
    } else
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
LogService.log("navigating to " + url);
}
```

This doesn't work. I still get to see the ugly unauthenticated.xhtml page and no redirect. If I debug I run through the code correctly so I know the event is always caught well and the check for the website works. If I got to the new url in the browser the correct page is displayed.

Now, if I remove this line

```
        e.Cancel = true;
```

I get closer to the result I want. Then I do get redirected to unauthenticated.xhtml, but within a second I am redirected again towards the correct page. So the warning flashes on the screen and disappears. (Makes sense: both Navigation events still go through)

I have also tried placing these two lines in this order:

```
        browser.Source = url;
        e.Cancel = true;
```

But the result didn't change.

How can I get a well working redirection from within the program?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could redirect, so what's your question now

Comment: I don't want to see the other website flash on my screen.

Comment: do you mean you dont want to show unauthenticated.xhtml page and  redirected towards the correct page directly?